# freeipa admin password reset

Tags: ldap, freeipa

I'm trying to figure out how to reset my freeipa3 admin password. I'm able to see the user when I search the domain:

```
 [root@ipaserver ipa]# LDAPTLS_CACERT=/etc/ipa/ca.crt ldapsearch -h localhost -ZZ -x -b uid=admin,cn=users,cn=compat,dc=central,dc=example,dc=com
 # extended LDIF
 #
 # LDAPv3
 # base <uid=admin,cn=users,cn=compat,dc=central,dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
 # filter: (objectclass=*)
 # requesting: ALL
 #

 # admin, users, compat, central.example.com
 dn: uid=admin,cn=users,cn=compat,dc=central,dc=example,dc=com
 objectClass: posixAccount
 objectClass: top
 gecos: Administrator
 cn: Administrator
 uidNumber: 1909600000
 gidNumber: 1909600000
 loginShell: /bin/bash
 homeDirectory: /home/admin
 uid: admin
```

[and I found this only snippet (it seems) on the web for resetting my password.](https://www.redhat.com/archives/freeipa-users/2011-May/msg00144.html)

When I try that however I get the following message:

```
 [root@ipaserver ipa]# LDAPTLS_CACERT=/etc/ipa/ca.crt ldappasswd -ZZ -D      'cn=directory manager' -W -S      uid=admin,cn=users,cn=compat,dc=central,dc=example,dc=com
 New password:
 Re-enter new password:
 Enter LDAP Password:
 Result: No such object (32)
 Additional info: Failed to update password
```

Anyone with past experience with resetting the admin freeIPA server that might have some suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use cn=compat entry for your password changes. cn=compat is read-only compatibility tree which is automatically generated against the primary data tree in cn=accounts. Compat tree entries have no passwords.

Your problem is that you are trying to change password of an entry that is purposedly read-only and that is implemented via a plugin purposedly not providing a password field in the entries.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand...do I not have any recourse at all for resetting the password for admin?

Comment: You can reset the password for admin but you are doing it wrong -- you are attempting to use *wrong* LDAP object, the one which has no password associated and is merely a display. Think about eating a cake and looking at the picture of a cake. You are trying to eat a picture of a cake in your example above.

All your IPA users are stored in cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=central,dc=example,dc=com subtree, not in cn=users,cn=compat,dc=central,dc=example,dc=com. Thus, your admin user is uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=central,dc=example,dc=com.

Answer (score 0):

update password with the ldappasswd utility. Change domain as you have.
first **export** then Try with Below.

```
# export LDAPTLS_CACERT=/etc/ipa/ca.crt
# ldappasswd -ZZ -D 'cn=directory manager' -W -S uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com -H ldap://ipa.example.com
New password:
Re-enter new password:
Enter LDAP Password:
```